# 'if not ' does not work with two or three 'and'

Tags: python-3.x

This the script:

```
num = 3
if not (num == 2 and num == 3):
    print('es 3')
```

## I would expect the 'print' not to run beause the 'and'

## it is not true

Comment: num could never be both 2 and 3 so `(num == 2 and num == 3)` will always be false therefor `not (num == 2 and num ==3)` will always be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly normal for the code to print `es 3` however I realise that it's often difficult to understand why so I'll break the code down here:

The first things we should check are `num == 2` and `num == 3`. Obviously `num == 3` will return `True` and `num == 2` will return `False` because `num` was assigned the value `3`.

Since one equality is false and the other is true the `and` operator returns false because `and` only returns `True` is both parameters are true.

So `(num == 2 and num == 3)` is False

However `not` will return the opposite boolean value so if you type `not True` you will get `False` and `not False` will return `True`

In this scenario what you typed is equivalent to `not False` therefore it will return `True` which means the `if` statement will execute and Python will print `es 3`